# How to subsample windows of a DataSet in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, subsampling

Let's say I have a `DataSet` that look like this:

```
Name    | Grade
---------------
Josh    | 94
Josh    | 87
Amanda  | 96
Karen   | 78
Amanda  | 90
Josh    | 88
```

I would like to create a new `DataSet` where each name has 3 rows, where the additional rows (if any) are sampled from the ones of the same name (so Karen will have three identical rows, for example).

How do I do that without looping through each name?

Answer (score 1):

Data preparation :

```
 val df = Seq(("Josh",94),("Josh",87),("Amanda",96),("Karen",78),("Amanda",90),("Josh",88)).toDF("Name","Grade")
```

**Perform the following , only if** your Data is `skewed` for a `Name` :
Add a random number, and filter the top 3 random numbers for each `Name`.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("random", round(rand()*10))

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("Name").orderBy("random")

val df3 = df2.withColumn("row_number",row_number.over(windowSpec))
             .filter($"row_number" <= 3)
```

Now, aggregate the values for each `Name` and duplicate 3 times to ensure we have atleast 3 records for each `Name`. Then finally take 1st 3 values, and `explode`

```
df4.groupBy("Name").agg(collect_list("Grade") as "grade_list")
.withColumn("temp_list", slice( flatten(array_repeat($"grade_list", 3)), 1,3))
.select($"Name",explode($"temp_list") as "Grade").show
```

**Notes :**

- Since the above code  will have max 3 values in `grade_list` , hence Duplicating it 3 times won't harm.
- Incase you don't use the `Window` step, you can have a combination of `when( size($"grade_list") === n, ).otherwise()` to above unnecessary duplication.